# Match quantity of items between two dataframes, based on SKU

Tags: python, pandas

I want to copy the information (quantity) of one dataframe's column to the other dataframe's quantity column but do so matching the SKU column.

So for example the dataframes look like:

```
Dataframe 1: 
SKU    Quantity      Title
A          3         Scissors
B          4         Cable
C          5         Goat
D          6         Cheese
```

```
Dataframe 2: 
SKU    Quantity      Title
A          1         Blue Scissors
B          2         Red Cables
C          1         Fat Goat
D          2         Smelly Cheese
```

So I would like to get Dataframe 1's quantities and place them into Dataframe 2, but matching the SKUs (A, B, C, D etc) even though some other columns (such as Title) might have different information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set index on `SKU` for both dataframes to align on index and copy the column `Quantity` with the aligned index.  Reset index to restore  `SKU` back to data column.

```
df1a = df1.set_index('SKU')
df2a = df2.set_index('SKU')

df2a['Quantity'] = df1a['Quantity']

df2 = df2a.reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)

  SKU  Quantity          Title
0   A         3  Blue Scissors
1   B         4     Red Cables
2   C         5       Fat Goat
3   D         6  Smelly Cheese
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
df2['Quantity'] = np.where(df1['SKU'] == df2['SKU'], df1['Quantity'])
```